# Erro ao tentar recuperar dados do MySQL com PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou fazendo uma página de Web que contém *login* para uma área administrativa,
porém onde eu estou criando e fazendo os testes (em um servidor local) está funcionando normalmente. Quando copio o projeto e coloco no meu notebook para testar e apresentar o projeto, o mesmo código apresenta erro.

Onde eu estou criando a página e testando é Linux, no meu notebook é Windows.

A rotina do MySQL é essa:

```
if (isset($_POST["f_logar"])) {

    $user=$_POST["f_user"];
    $senha=$_POST["f_senha"];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_colaboradores WHERE username='$user' AND senha='$senha'";
    $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    $ret=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

    //MySQL
    //pesq.user, se existir
    //obter user e senha
    //comparar. senha

    if($ret == 0){

        echo "<p id='lgErro'>Login inválido</p>";

    }else{
        $chave1="abcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwyz";
        $chave2="ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ";
        $chave3="0123456789";
        $chave=str_shuffle($chave1.$chave2.$chave3);
        $tam=strlen($chave);
        $num="";
        $qtde=rand(20,50);

        for ($i=0;$i<$qtde;$i++) { 

            $pos=rand(0,$tam);
            $num.=substr($chave,$pos,1);
        }

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['numlogin']=$num;
        $_SESSION['username']=$user;
        $_SESSION['acesso']=$ret['acesso']; //0=restrito / 1=total

        header("Location:gerenciamento.php?num=$num");
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

O erro que apresenta no notebook é esse:

> Warnig: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\site\login.php on line 28

Comment: Antes da linha 28, logo após `mysqli_query`, coloque `die(mysqli_error($con))` e veja se alguma mensagem de erro aparece na tela.

Comment: Aparece Champ 'username' inconnu dans where clause

Comment: A coluna `username` existe na tabela `tb_colaboradores`?

Comment: nosssaaaa que vacilo estava com user na tabela e estava chamando username. muito obrigado [resolvido]

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer a verificação de linhas retornadas e caso retorne mais que `0` ai você pega o(s) dado(s) retornado(s):

```
if (isset($_POST["f_logar"])) {

    $user=$_POST["f_user"];
    $senha=$_POST["f_senha"];

    $sql="SELECT * FROM tb_colaboradores WHERE username='$user' AND senha='$senha'";

    $res = mysqli_query($sql);

    //MySQL
    //pesq.user, se existir
    //obter user e senha
    //comparar. senha

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) <= 0){

        echo "<p id='lgErro'>Login inválido</p>";

    }else{

        $ret=mysqli_fetch_array($res, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        $chave1="abcdfghijklmnopqrstuvwyz";
        $chave2="ABCDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZ";
        $chave3="0123456789";
        $chave=str_shuffle($chave1.$chave2.$chave3);
        $tam=strlen($chave);
        $num="";
        $qtde=rand(20,50);

        for ($i=0;$i<$qtde;$i++) { 

            $pos=rand(0,$tam);
            $num.=substr($chave,$pos,1);
        }

        session_start();
        $_SESSION['numlogin']=$num;
        $_SESSION['username']=$user;
        $_SESSION['acesso']=$ret['acesso']; //0=restrito / 1=total

        header("Location:gerenciamento.php?num=$num");
    }
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

Além disso, adicionei um `MYSQLI_ASSOC` para retornar os valores em `array`

Comment: o que mais me entriga é que a mesma rotina funciona aonde o site esta sendo construido e testado que no caso é o meu PC.